# Error in getting JSON data in a variable

Tags: json, variables

This is my code

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("Old.json");
var x={};
x=oModel.getData();
console.log(x.EntryCollection);
```

This is my Old.json file:

```
{"EntryCollection":[{
"sender": "",
"icon": "",
"info": "",
"text": ""}]
}
```

I am getting undefined in console.log. Where am I going wrong??